# Exclude columns of pandas dataframe based on aggregated count of its rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
   Fruit                John      Mary        Paul     Anna
   Apples                1         1            1       5
   Oranges               2         2            2       3
   Lemons                1         1            4       1
   Berries               2         2            2       7
```

and I also have the following nested dictionaries:

```
{Apples:{5:1,1:3},Oranges:{3:1,2:3},Lemons:{4:1,1:3},Berries:{7:1,2:3}}
```

which tells me that

1. 1 person has 5 apples and 3 persons have 1 apple
2. 1 person has 3 oranges and 3 persons have 2 oranges
3. 1 person has 4 lemons and 3 persons have 1 lemon
4. 1 person has 7 berries and 3 persons have 2 berries

What I need now is to extract the people who either have 5 apples, or 3 oranges, or 4 lemons, or 7 berries, i.e. all the unique cases in the above dictionary.

This means that since Mary for example is in no fruit a unique person, but always within the 3 same pieces category, will be excluded.

I can do that with an ugly sequence of complex and bad performing for loops, but I was wondering whether there is a more `pandas` efficient way to do this.

Expected Ouput:

```
   Fruit           Paul     Anna
   Apples            2       5
   Oranges           2       3
   Lemons            4       1
   Berries           2       7
```

Comment: What is expected output? How looks final DataFrame?

Comment: updated with expected output

Comment: Shouldn't Paul have `0`/`None` apples given your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `from_dict` and `isin`

```
d = {'Apples':{5:1,1:3},'Oranges':{3:1,2:3},'Lemons':{4:1,1:3},'Berries':{7:1,2:3}}
```

Convert the above dict keys to `df`

```
# df1 = pd.DataFrame([[k for k in j.keys()] for i, j in d.items()])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*list(d.values())))).T

df[df.isin(df1[0])].dropna(how='all', axis=1).fillna(df).set_index(df.Fruit)

# Output:

         Paul   Anna
Fruit       
Apples   1.0    5.0
Oranges  2.0    3.0
Lemons   4.0    1.0
Berries  2.0    7.0
```

Comment: `df1 = df.from_dict({i:{y:x for x,y in j.items()} for i,j in d.items()}).T` takes only the first instance with count 1. For example if I have two values in my dictionary `d={Key1:{5:1,6:1}}` it will only return 5 and not both 5 and 6 in the column 1 (that contains all values with 1 count)

Comment: @user37143 In that case use a list comprehension to get all the values from dictionary. I'll update the answer. It should work now with duplicate values.

Comment: @user37143 Happy to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your nested dictionary is not actually an essential part of the process and you just want to work out which people correspond to a unique value in any row, we can do the following:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd


data = StringIO('''Fruit                John      Mary        Paul     Anna
Apples                1         1            1       5
Oranges               2         2            2       3
Lemons                1         1            4       1
Berries               2         2            2       7''')

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\s+').set_index('Fruit')

tr = df.transpose()
mask = ~pd.DataFrame({c: tr.duplicated(c, keep=False) for c in tr.columns}).all(axis=1)

df = df[mask.index[mask]]
```

We set the index to `'Fruit'` and then transpose to get one column per `'Fruit'` and one row per person. Then we create a mask which determines whether the value in the column is a duplicate of any others, and check if this is true in all cases. then, we can filter the columns in our original dataframe using this mask.

This gives us the following as `df`:

```
         Paul  Anna
Fruit              
Apples      1     5
Oranges     2     3
Lemons      4     1
Berries     2     7
```

Answer (score 1):

you can assign the Fruit as index for the dataframe, and with respect to conditions of fruits you can extract the column name.

```
        John    Mary    Paul    Anna
Fruit               
Apples  3   1   2   5
Oranges 2   2   2   3
Lemons  1   1   4   1
Berries 2   2   2   7

df.set_index(['Fruit'],inplace=True)
column_names = df.apply(lambda x:x.name  if ((x.loc['Apples']==5) | (x.loc['Oranges']==3) | (x.loc['Lemons']==4) | (x.loc['Berries']==7)) else None)
df[list(filter(None,column_names))]
```

Out:

```
    Paul    Anna
Fruit       
Apples  2   5
Oranges 2   3
Lemons  4   1
Berries 2   7
```

Comment: Thanks, and if I want to itterate automatically over the columns (without inputting them in the or condition of the apply function)? I am asking because in my case I have 30.000 such columns and I can not hard code all of them.

Comment: Yes , you can iterate. The solution work perfectly even if you have 30000 columns. But if you have 30000 fruits conditions, we may need of putting conditions in "lambda" function :-) .